# How to remove a pipenv's PipFile, PipFile.lock and associated virtualenv?

Tags: python, pipenv

To create a `pipenv` for a python project, I first created a project folder and go into the folder to instruct `pipenv` to create the `Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock` and associated virtual environment like so:

```
$ mkdir Project
$ cd Project
$ pipenv --three
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.5.2) to create virtualenv…
⠋Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-jrsJaPdI/bin/python3
Also creating executable in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-jrsJaPdI/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/Projects-jrsJaPdI
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
$
$ pipenv install --dev
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (711973)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (711973)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run the following:
 $ pipenv shell
```

Is the proper way of removing all that `pipenv` had create simply doing the following in the Project directory when not in `pipenv shell` mode:

```
$ pipenv --rm
$ rm Pipfil*
```

Meaning I have to remove the Project folder's virtual environment first followed by removing the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` subsequently?

Answer (score 8):

Here we are:

```
# Removing venv directory ...
$ pipenv --rm

# ... and Pipfile, Pipfile.lock
$ rm Pipfile*

# Strange that deleted venv still activated, so exit from it.
$ exit
```